# Rerender a pageblock

Tags: salesforce

If I run the page first time, all pageblocks shows the message "choose an user, account or opp" because nothing is choosen. But if I already have selected a user, account or opp the pageblock will show a list/detail of the account or opp. 
If I change the user at the top, I want that all panel/pageblocks will resetet, but how can I do that?
I added all pageblocks to the rerender function, but it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

```
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock id="pbUser">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:OutputPanel >
            <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedUserId}" size="1" multiselect="false">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListOfUser}" /> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchAccounts}" <u><b>rerender="pbAcc, pbOpp, pbOppD"</b></u>/>              
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:OutputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageblock <u><b>id="pbAcc"</b></u>>
    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(AccList.size >0,true,false)}" id="pbsAcc">
        <apex:outputpanel style="overflow:scroll;height:200px;" layout="block" id="panelAcc">
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!AccList}" var="Acc" onRowClick="highlightAcc(this)">
                <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Acc.Name}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!fetchOpps}" <u><b>rerender="pbOpp, pbOppD"</b></u>>
                        <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedAccountId}" value="{!Acc.Id}" name="SelectedAccountId"/>
                    </apex:actionSupport>
                </apex:column>        
                <apex:column headervalue="Street">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Acc.BillingStreet}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headervalue="City">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Acc.BillingCity}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblocktable>   
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(AccList.size <1,true,false)}">
        <apex:outputpanel style="overflow:scroll;height:200px;" layout="block">
           Choose a User.
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>

<apex:pageblock <u><b>id="pbOpp"</b></u>>
    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(OppList.size >0,true,false)}" id="pbsOpp">
        <apex:outputpanel style="overflow:scroll;height:200px;" layout="block" id="panelOpp">
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!OppList}" var="Opp" onRowClick="highlightOpp(this)">
                <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Opp.Name}"/>{!Opp.Id}
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!fetchOppDetail}" <u><b>rerender="pbOppD"</b></u>>
                        <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedOppId}" value="{!Opp.Id}" name="SelectedOppId"/>
                    </apex:actionSupport>
                </apex:column>        
                <apex:column headervalue="Amount">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Opp.Amount}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblocktable>   
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(OppList.size <1,true,false)}">
        <apex:outputpanel style="overflow:scroll;height:200px;" layout="block">
            Choose an account.
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>

<apex:pageblock <u><b>id="pbOppD"</b></u> mode="inlineEdit">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveInlineChanges}" value="Save" id="saveButton"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!fetchOppDetail}" value="Cancel" id="cancelButton"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(OppDetail.size >0,true,false)}" id="pbsOppD">
        <apex:outputpanel style="overflow:scroll;height:200px;" layout="block" id="panelOppD">
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!OppDetail}" var="OppD">
                <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!OppD.Name}">
                        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                    </apex:outputfield>
                </apex:column>        
                <apex:column headervalue="Amount">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!OppD.Amount}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblocktable>   
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(OppDetail.size <1,true,false)}">
        <apex:outputpanel style="overflow:scroll;height:200px;" layout="block">
            Chosse an opportunity.
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>

</apex:form>
```

Thanks,
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you have some misplaced html in you `actionSupport` definition. Change:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchAccounts}" <u><b>rerender="pbAcc, pbOpp, pbOppD"</b></u>/>
```

To:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchAccounts}" rerender="pbAcc, pbOpp, pbOppD"/>
```

(This applies to the other `actionSupport` elements further down the page also)